# Google Docs API with zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-docs-api

I'm trying to read a Doc from Google with an authorized user and output the content through my page.

Everything works fine, and the output is Ok, but after few seconds, a popup window appears with an error **"Google Docs has encountered an error. We are looking into the problem now. Please try one of these interim solutions: Reload this page"**

My code is this:

```
<?php
  require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Docs');
  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Docs_Query');

  $service = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
  $client_grabmark = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient('MYUSER@gmail.com', 'MYPASS', $service);
  $service = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($client_grabmark); 
  $service->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);


  $contentLink = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/'DOCID'/edit';

  $data = $service->get($contentLink)->getBody();

  ob_start();
  echo $data;
  ob_flush();
  exit  
?>
```

What I'm doing wrong? If I try export to PDF everything is Ok (I just have to change the link), but I want to show the page as if I was in Google Docs.

Any help?
Best Regards
DF

Answer (score 2):

You cannot output the HTML content of a Google Doc page into the context of your own page and get that to work.  If you want to show a document to a user, redirect them to the Google Doc itself, using an HTTP Location header.

```
<?php
header("Location: $contentLink");
?>
```

If the user you had intended to display the doc to does not have permission to access the doc, there are two options:

1. Share the doc to the user using the Documents List API.
2. Export the document as text, HTML, or PDF using the API, and then display it to the user.

These options are detailed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/).

Comment: I cannot redirect to the Google Doc itself because the end user of my page because it doesn't have permissions in the document. I use my credentials to read the Document and then I want to output the document to others.

Comment: Hello Vic.Thanks for your answer, but I've already read the documentation and I know these two options. The first option, is not good for what I want and the second works fine for some documents but not for Spreadsheets. I've developed a third options (the one I explained in my first question) **and it works**. My page realy outputs the Google Docs, but the page is always trying to refresh and kept getting the error described.

Comment: The second option will also work for spreadsheets, as spreadsheets have PDF export.

I'm sorry to say that the option you've developed does not work.  You've even proven it doesn't work.  There are numerous cross-domain scripting issues that cannot be resolved by yielding the Google Docs output from your own domain/app.  Besides that, you're trying to circumvent the Google Docs security model, which is yet another reason Google Docs will not allow this.

Please try again with option 2 that I proposed.  The documentation mentions how to export spreadsheets.

Comment: Hi Vic. Thanks again for your answer. It seems i have to stay with the export option. I know that spreadsheets can be exported to PDF, but the result is not very good, i'll try the HTML export. I'm having another problem now, when I have a PDF document in Google Docs, I cannot use the same link (as documents) to export to PDF, because the document is already a PDF. Do you know how can I get those documents?

Comment: Documents that are already a PDF can be downloaded at their "content" link, which is a field provided with every resource entry from the API.

Comment: Can you explain this better. I still can't get uploaded files (like PDF, zip, ...). What's the "content" link? How can I get it from the URL (I have this URL https://docs.google.com/file/d/'DOCID'/edit. How can I get the content link?)

Comment: Felix, are you using the Google Documents List API?

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#downloading_documents_and_files

Comment: Yes, of course, like I said in my initial question. I'm using the API with ZEND.